# Python and Selenium filling in dynamic form with hidden fields

Tags: python, selenium, ui-automation

I am trying to automate running through an airline site. It requires login, which I have managed to do in Python using Selenium.

However the form to fill in has 2 issues.
1. Choosing the departure city with Selenium fails because the field is hidden. I have got around this by using javascript to set it as visible.
2. The destination city field is only populated with option once the departure city has been chosen. Using Selenium, the site doesn't seem to accept that the departure city has been selected, so the list never populates.

This is the code from the site:

```
                <div class="input depart-city select combobox no-regions">
                <label for="departCity" class="visuallyhidden">Departure City </label>
                <select name="departCity" id="departCity" title="Departure City" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Departure City</option>
    <option value="FRA">Frankfurt</option>
    <option value="MUC">Munich</option>
</select>
<input placeholder="Departure City" title="Departure City" autocomplete="off" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"><button type="button" class="ui-button icon-arrow-down ui-button-icon" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items"> </button>

            <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;"></ul></div>

            <div class="input destination-city select combobox" id="destinationLinkSelect">
                <label for="destCity" class="visuallyhidden">Destination City </label>


                    <select name="destCity" id="destCity" title="Destination City " style="display: none;">
                        <option value="">Destination City </option>
                    </select><input placeholder="Destination City " title="Destination City " autocomplete="off" class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"><button type="button" class="ui-button icon-arrow-down ui-button-icon" tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items"> </button>

            <ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="z-index: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;"></ul></div>
```

My code looks like this:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# browser.set_window_size(1124, 850)
driver.get("https://www.flysaa.com/de/en/voyagerLogin.secured")
assert "Voyager" in driver.title
driver.find_element_by_name("voyagerId").send_keys("######")
driver.find_element_by_name("pin").send_keys("####")
driver.find_element_by_name("loginButton").click()
time.sleep(5)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ad1"))
    )
except:
    print "Page didn't load!"
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("South Africa(English)").click()
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("country")).select_by_value("DE")
driver.find_element_by_id("changeRegionAndLanguages").click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_id("voyagerFlightSearch").send_keys(Keys.TAB)
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('departCity').style.display='inline-block';")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('destCity').style.display='inline-block';")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('departDay').style.display='inline-block';")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('departMonthYear').style.display='inline-block';")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('chkReturn').style.display='inline-block';")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('preferredClass').style.display='inline-block';")
driver.find_element_by_id("departCity").send_keys("Frankfurt" + Keys.TAB)
time.sleep(3)
Select(driver.find_element_by_name("destCity")).select_by_value("JNB")
driver.find_element_by_id("destCity").send_keys(Keys.TAB)
Select(driver.find_element_by_name("departDay")).select_by_value("01")
#driver.find_element_by_name("departMonthYear").select_by_value("Oct-2017")
#driver.find_element_by_name("chkReturn").click()
#driver.find_element_by_name("preferredClass").select_by_value("1")
time.sleep(10)
#assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

Any ideas? I think the Aria-haspopup is causing my issues, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If a GUI test is based on direct interactions with hidden elements, you are not doing what a real user would do on the page. This fact renders the test pretty much pointless. Try to achieve what you want by doing things a real user could also do.

Comment: I agree, it seems to be the way this site was designed though. It is hidden unless you click on it.

Comment: Then do so, click on it. ;-) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to avoid applying `JavaScript` and simulate real user behavior:

```
# Click arrow-button to open drop-down
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@title="Show All Items"]').click()
# Select required option
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Frankfurt').click()
```

In the same way you can handle "Destination" field:

```
# Click arrow-button to open drop-down
driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//button[@title="Show All Items"])[2]').click()
# Select required option
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Calgary').click()
```

Comment: Thanks, that picks the the list correctly, but it doesn't seem to click on the Frankfurt option. It highlights it, but doesn't click it. So then the second list doesn't get populated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using @Andersson's answer. However, the site doesn't work with selecting from the list, or typing into the combobox. It needs for arrows to select the option as if a mouse was clicking on it.

My code for that section is here:

```
    driver.find_element_by_id("voyagerFlightSearch").send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@title="Show All Items"]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('ui-widget').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN + Keys.ARROW_DOWN + Keys.ARROW_DOWN + Keys.TAB)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('(//button[@title="Show All Items"])[2]').click()
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ui-widget')[2].send_keys("Johannesburg (OR Tambo)" + Keys.TAB)
```